# Linq with entities

Tags: wcf, linq, silverlight, entities

I am starting to develop a system using silverlight 5 with wcf ria.  I use Visual studio 2010 and the code is in visual basic.  In my application I have a table `guiasidiomas`. It is a very simple table:

- Id
- Idguia
- Ididioma

In the application I changed the query `getguiasidiomas` that is generated by the domain service

```
Public Function GetGuiasIdiomas(ByVal idProcurado As String) AsIQueryable(Of GuiasIdioma)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.GuiasIdiomas.Where(Function(c) (c.idGuia).ToString = idProcurado)
End Function
```

I inserted a where in order to filter by a given idguia.
That is the query that has a problem.
If you could help me I would appreciate very much.
When I run the query I get:

> SCRIPT5022: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
>   Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError
>   Message: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'GetGuiasIdiomas'. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1):

Linq-to-Entities cannot translate `.ToString()` directly to SQL, so you cannot use it in your `WHERE` clause.  Here are two options:

1. Convert `idProcurado` to the same datatype as `idGuia` and compare directly
2. Pull ALL entities from the database (e.g. by calling `.AsEnumerable()`) and doing the comparison against the object list.

I'm guessing 1) is going to give you better performance by only puling back one or a small number of entities.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message says, linq to entities does not support `ToString`.
You can prepare list of strings before using it with linq to entities.